# Run non static method on current activity from another class

Tags: java, android

I am struggling to figure out how to simply call and run a method from a class (that is not an activity) on my current activity.

my current code:

**CustomListViewAdapter.java** (other class)

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = Photos.listView.getPositionForView(v);
            Log.v("value  ", "tada" + position);
            Photos photos = new Photos();
            photos.deletePhoto(position);

        }
    });
```

**Photos.java** (my current activity class)

```
public void deletePhoto(int pos){
    Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "delete index:"+pos , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mylist.remove(pos);
    setupListView();
}
```

Problem is, this way of doing it makes a new instance of mylist which gives me a outofbounds error. How can I do this correctly so I get the current activity and update it accordingly?

Comment: Why don't you want to make it static?

Comment: Why do you have an onclick in the adapter? Why don't you set the onclick in the activity?

Comment: @jiduvah because it needed to be within my getView of the custom list view adapter so I know the index of which button was clicked

Comment: do you have multiple buttons within each listitem?

Comment: no I have just have a listview with clickable cells and 1 button per cell

Comment: Hmmm, I think there is a better solution but I am unsure exactly what you need to do. Do you need to have an onclick for the cell and for the button?

Comment: yes I do unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a static method, you could create in interface.

```
public interface DeleteInterface {
    public void deletePhoto(int position);
}
```

And then in your adapter's constructor...

```
private DeleteInterface mInterface;

public CustomListAdapter(/* other paramaters */ DeleteInterface interface) {
    // other assignments
    mInterface = interface;
}
```

And then in your Activity...

```
public class Photos extends Activity implements DeleteInterface {
    // your code here

    public void deletePhoto(int pos) {
        // your method here
    }
}
```

But make sure that when you create your Adapter, you have a pointer to the current Activity and pass it through the Adapter's constructor.

Last but not least...

In your adapter, call `mInterface.deletePhoto(position);` to call your Activity's method.

Comment: what does passing a pointer of my current activity look like?

Comment: this is what my adapter call looks like now    `CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, rowItems );`

Comment: To answer my question - I needed to pass `this`